# Sys::Info - Question

Tags: perl, device

From [Sys::Info::Device](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys%3a%3aInfo%3a%3aDevice):
`If DEVICE_ID has the value of available, then the names of the available devices will be returned.`

Why does `$info->device('available');` return no devices when there is at least the cpu-device?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Sys::Info;

my $info = Sys::Info->new;

my @available = $info->device('available');
say 'Available devices: ', scalar @available;

my $cpu = $info->device( 'CPU' );
say 'Number of cores: ', $cpu->count;
```

Output:

> Available devices: 0
>   Number of cores: 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same output running this on a Mac OS X box. You might contact the [developer](http://search.cpan.org/~burak/Sys-Info-Base-0.78/lib/Sys/Info/Device.pm#AUTHOR).